# Formidable Node module... How to get non-file field names/values before file upload progress starts

Tags: node.js, formidable

I am using Node's formidable module for form processing. Works perfect. Now I need to have access to the non-file field names/values posted before the file upload starts. The field names/values are available only AFTER the file uploads are done. Is there any way to get the field names before the file uploads start?

```
 formProcess = new formidable.IncomingForm();
 ...
 formProcess.parse(req, function(error, myFields, myFiles) {

    //I get access to the field values here...
    //But only after the files are uploaded. 
    //I need this info before the file uploads start.
 }
 ..
 formProcess.on('progress', function(alreadyReceived, expectedToRcv) {
   //Fileupload progress info available here...
   //I need field names here while processing the upload progress.
   //Application specific requirement...
 }
```

Does this have to do with how http post method works or is it specific to the implementation of Node's Formidable module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [`file`](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable#file) and [`field`](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable#field) events that are emitted. Just make sure your non-file fields come before your file fields in your form since fields are sent/received in order.

Comment: That and this helped... formProcess.on('field', function(name, value) {  });  This "field" event is emitted before the fileupload progress kicks in.